# The Cauchy-Crofton formula on a plane

Tags: differential-geometry, integral-geometry

For the complete tutorial for the formula you can check Do Carmo's Differential Geometry of Curves & Surfaces page through 42-46 at section 1.7.

The formula $$\iint n(p,\theta)dpd\theta=2 Len(\alpha)$$
For finite length regular plane curve $\alpha$ and $n$ is count of intersection of lines with curve.

My question is:

I understand that to find global property we have to define some measure on lines in the real plane. What I don't understand is what does this integral actually mean?

Elaboration of my confusion:

In the proof for a curve with length
$l$

> [image]
> he proves as above(at least gives a sketch)

So the integral(so called measure) $\iint dpd\theta$ is evaluated according to some generic line.

But if I want to calculate for, lets say circle with radii $r$, I calculate it as if $p$ and $\theta$ parametrize the circle. $2(Len(circ))=2(2\pi)=\iint \limits_{0\le p\le r,0\le \theta\le 2\pi}\underbrace{n}_{2}dpd\theta=2(2\pi)$

So what is we are actually doing?

Comment: I have been working a long time on these questions and I can give, so I think, a good intuitive insight about Crofton's formula, but I will not write something before I have a comment from you to my answer https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3901760 to one of your recent questions: this site is based on dialog.

Answer (score 1):

You get $2(2\pi r)$ in both cases, of course. You are integrating over the region in the space $(p,\theta)$ of lines corresponding to lines that intersect the circle of radius $r$ centered at the origin. The lines with $p>r$ do not intersect the circle (so then $n=0$); the lines with $p=r$ intersect the circle once, tangentially (so then $n=1$); the lines with $p<r$ intersect the circle twice. So you get, indeed,
$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^r 2\,dp\,d\theta = 2\pi(2r) = 2(2\pi r)$, which is twice the length of the curve.