# Fitting circle in $f(x)=x^3-3x^2$ what is the radius?

Tags: geometry, systems-of-equations

[image]

The whole problem is the above.

I tried to solve it analytically but I couldnot find enough equation to solve it.

Assume the center is $(a,-r)$ where $r$ is the radius of the circle.

The points on the sphere $(x-a)^2+(y+r)^2=r^2$

and $(x,f(x))$ must satisfy it so if we denote the intersection points $(x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2)$:

$$(x_1-a)^2+(x_1^3-3x_1^2+r)^2=r^2$$
$$(x_2-a)^2+(x_2^3-3x_2^2+r)^2=r^2$$

Are two equation with 4 unknown.

Can you give me elegant relations between these two unknowns?

Comment: As the circle is tangent to the curve at those points, that should be the minimum distance from center $(a,-r)$ to the curve. Taking distance between two straight points and minimizing it using derivative should give couple of more equations. But whichever way you look at it, it is ugly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a different path that can be considered maybe as "elegant" by building a kind of (generalized) angle bissector.

Take a look at the following figure: the red curve is the locus of the center of circles that are tangent to the (blue) curve and the (green) $x$ axis. The final answer to your question is that the center of the circle has coordinates

$$a=1.80155263360, \ \ -r=-1.06021721502$$

The abscissas of the tangency points with the curve being:

$$x_1=0.79999363787 \ \ \text{and} \ \ \ x_2=2.85193070410.
$$

How have these results been found ?

Let

$$p:=\sqrt{1+f'(m)^2}\tag{1}$$

This swallow-tailed curve has parametric equations:

$$\begin{cases} \ \ a_m&=&m-\dfrac{f'(m)r}{p}&=&\ \ \ \color{red}{m}&+&(p-1)\dfrac{f(m)}{f'(m)}\\
-r_m&=&\dfrac{f(m)p(p-1)}{f'(m)^2}&=&\color{red}{f(m)}&-&(p-1)\dfrac{f(m)}{f'(m)^2}\end{cases}\tag{2}$$

(where $m$ has the following meaning: $(m,f(m))$ is the point of tangency of a circle tangent (at least once) to the blue curve with center $(a_m,-r_m)$ ).

All boils down to the obtention of a double point in a parametric curve. I have used numerical methods for this purpose (an analytical solution looks out of reach, due in particular to the square root in (1)).

Explanation for (2): Let us express that the center of the current circle is at the same distance $r$ from the curve and from the $x$ axis by finding a unit vector on the normal to the blue curve at point $\binom{m}{f(m)}$, a property that can be expressed in the following way:

$$\binom{m}{f(m)}+r \underbrace{\dfrac{1}{p}\binom{-f'(m)}{1}}_{\text{unit normal vector}}=\binom{a}{-r},  \ \ \ p \ \text{has been defined in (1)}$$

giving two equalities from which one can extract $r$ then $a$ (see (2)).

[image]

Comment: I have somewhat improved my solution.

Comment: perfect and accurate, but a bit complicated.

Answer (score 2):

The following is only a hint, not an answer.

The rest of the equations involves the derivative, since the line connecting the center with a tangent point is perpendicular to the tangent line. Hence for $i=1,2$:

$$\frac{-1}{f'(x_i)} = \frac {-r-f(x_i)}{a-x_i}$$

which gives two extra equations

$$x_i^3-3x_i^2+r =\frac {x_i-a}{-3x_i(x_i-1)}$$

Familiar terms surface, but I'm not sure how solving these four equations can be elegant.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

In figure suppose AC is straight line.We first find the angle BAC the curve makes with x axis:

$y=x^3-3x^2$ ⇒ $y'=3x^2-6x$

⇒ $tan (\widehat{BAC})=y'$ at point A(3, 0):

$tan (\widehat{BAC})=3^3-6\times 3=9$

⇒ $ \widehat{BAC} ≈83^o$

⇒$ \widehat{BAC}=\widehat BAD ≈41.5^o$

So the center of circle is on line $y=(m=tan 41.5)(x-3)$

Now we use plain geometry. we have:

$AB^2+(BD=r)^2=AD^2$

$BD^2+r^2=OD^2$

$AB+BO=3$

$(AB+BO)^2=AB^2+OB^2+2\cdot AB\cdot BO$

⇒ $AB^2+OB^2-2r^2=9-(DA^2+OD^2)$

$tan(41.5)=\frac r{AB}$

$OD^2=OB^2+r^2=(3-AB)^2+r^2$

These two relations give $OD^2$ in terms of r.

$sin(41.5)=\frac r{AD}$

This relation gives AD in term of r.

Now in relation:

$AB^2+OB^2-2r^2=9-(DA^2+OD^2)$

$OB=3-AB$

So OB can also be found in term of r. Plugging, DA, OA, AB and OB in above relation give an equation in terms of r

Note, r ≈1.1 and coordinates of its center is D( ≈1.8,  ≈-1.1)

Comment: Have you seen my solution ?